# Where does it show up when you post a "score" to the Facebook Scores API?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm posting scores from an Android Facebook game, and I'm getting back 'true', but I don't see the story anywhere. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook seems to have some logic in place to only post stories based on scores some of the time.

You can use the API to check someone's current score, by issuing a `GET` request to the same resource you used to post the score

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{userid}/scores?access_token={app_access_token}
```